# Can I do PDO prepare statements with array and foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, prepared-statement

So I legit started to read about PDO and PDO statemnts to update my code and give it more security, but I don't really know if this is ok or is it possible to make injections. I also sanitize the data before making the array. I made this function o add data given the name table and an array with the columns names and values like this

```
$tabla = 'tabla'
$datos = array(
        'id' => 'NULL',
        'id_usuario' => "'{$usuario['id']}'",
        'id_tipo' => "'{$tipo}'",
        'id_estado' => "'{$estado}'",
        'id_visibilidad' => "'{$visibilidad}'",
        'titulo' => "'{$titulo}'",
        'contenido' => "'{$contenido}'",
        'fecha' => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
      );

function pdo_agregar($tabla, $datos) {
  global $pdo;
  $columnas = implode(', ', array_keys($datos));
  $valores = implode(', ', array_values($datos));
  $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla ($columnas) VALUES ($valores)");
  foreach($datos as $indice => $valor) {
    $sentencia->bindParam(':'.$indice, $valor);
  }
  if($sentencia->execute()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  $sentencia->close();
  $pdo->close();
}
```

Is this okay? o Do i have to make statements like

> $sentencia = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (col, col2, col3)
>   VALUES (:col, :col2, :col3");

And then bind params individually?

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need these bind things, you can throw directly an array to the execute function of PDO (which does this binding for you).

My array is as follow `["data" => "mydata", "data2" = "mysecond"]` so I would generate a query like:

```
INSERT INTO `Tab`(`data`, `data2`) VALUES (:data, :data2)
```

And the code would be:

```
        foreach($data as $key=>$val){
            $keys[] = $key;
            $vals[] = ":".$key;
        }
        $keys = "`".implode("`,`", $keys)."`";
        $vals = implode(",", $vals);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `".$tab."`(".$keys.") VALUES (".$vals.")";
        $prep_insert = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $prep_insert->execute($data);
```

By the way, you should use classes and this, instead of this global things.

Comment: Thank you! Also, why is it better to use classes instead of this?

Comment: its better to read and u use functions still in classes but its more organized, u do this pdo connection one time on creating the class and u can use it from every function here is a pdo class of mine, maybe u see what i mean https://github.com/rautex/ccrm/blob/master/PDO_Class.php

Comment: Thank you so much @StefanBD ! I apreciate it

Comment: np, btw u should put $tabla  in ``, we had mutch trouble with our prev coder who dont did this, for example we wanted add the field alter(german for age) but this is a reserved word of mysql so we where very confused why the data was not saved

Comment: Please use proper English, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @mw509 The comment is because I have edited the question that was written using "abbreviated" language but it makes it difficult for non-English people to understand, and it's also encouraged by the help to write correctly. Also, this is a question of a new user so it's better to teach them now.

Comment: understood. Thank you for explaining. Your reputation makes sense all over again.

Comment: I will try to spend attention next times on it, as German I see  having "tiny" problems with slanging in English language.